# RSpec + Factory Girl Test 404 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, factory-bot

I have this in my controller spec file

```
it "should raise 404" do
      business = FactoryGirl.build(:business)
      expect{get :edit, :id => business}.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
    end
```

if I am right, build does not save to the database, so business should not exist, and my test should pass, but it does not.

I also tried a string as a value of "id", but it still fails.

I have tried with this controller action:

```
def edit
    if params[:id].to_i == 0
      name = params[:id].to_s.titleize
      @business = Business.find_by_name!(name)
    else
      @business = Business.find(params[:id])
    end
    respond_with(@business)
  end
```

an ID that does not exist, and it does indeed show a 404.

If you ask why a condition like that, I also make this action respond to a string for the "id" param.

Any ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound is received by this code in the application controller:

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :record_not_found

  private
    def record_not_found
      render :text => "404 Not Found Baby!", :status => 404
    end
```

why is my test for a 404 not passing?

Comment: Did you try sticking a breakpoint in there to see what your controller is doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your controller does not raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception, it rescues from it in ApplicationController. So try to test for response code or text, something like

```
  it "should respond with a 404" do
    business = FactoryGirl.build(:business)
    get :edit, :id => business
    response.response_code.should == 404
  end
```

Comment: tried your answer and this too: response.status.should be(404) but it still fails

Comment: Do you have any rescues for ActionController::RoutingError ? Guess you should get no route error since :id = nil . Try get :edit, :id => 999 that should work.

Comment: accepting this as answer; manual ids should work, it seems that factorygirl's build method represents an existing object

Comment: @ants advice is definitely worth considering, but here are a few comments about the example above that may help future readers:

* `FactoryGirl.build` creates the object, but does not persist it. The controller is querying for an object you haven't saved yet, which doesn't seem to be exactly what you want here…  

* If you have a persisted object, then this is likely better: `get :edit, :id => business.id` (even if rails extracts the id for you, using implicit test data makes your specs clearer)…    

* Since you are testing for a non-existant record, I'd skip building the factory altogether…

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late to the party, but you shouldn't really be creating records in controller tests. You create records in model tests.

In your controller tests, if you are expecting a create to fail, stub it with something like `my_model.stub(:save).and_return(false)`. If you are expecting create to be successful, you could stub it with `my_model.stub(:save).and_return(true)`

Using Shoulda....

```
context "record valid" do
  before :each do
    my_model.stub(:save).and_return(true)
    post :create
  end
  it { should redirect_to(dashboard_url) }
end
```